# Create variants of products with null option_value label using BigCommerce v3 API

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, api, bigcommerce

I am using Bigcommerce v3 API to create products on bigcommerce store. I have a product with two variants having following options

```
Size                 Self Life      Dot info
1L Glass Amber       
500ml Glass Amber    12           Methanol Sol.
```

When I am trying to create product like this

```
{
  "name": "Product name",
  "type": "physical",
  "sku": "CDID-12345",
  "description": "Description",
  "weight": 0,
  "width": 0,
  "depth": 0,
  "height": 0,
  "price": 0,
  "cost_price": 0,
  "retail_price": 0,
  "sale_price": 0,
  "categories": [1],
  "variants": [
    {
      "cost_price": 0,
      "price": 0,
      "weight": 0,
      "sku": "MP091236",
      "option_values": [
        {
          "option_display_name": "Size",
          "label": "1L Glass Amber",
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "cost_price": 0,
      "price": 0,
      "weight": 0,
      "sku": "MP091239",
      "option_values": [
        {
          "option_display_name": "Size",
          "label": "500ml Glass Amber",
        },
        {
          "option_display_name": "Self Life",
          "label": "12",
        },
        {
          "option_display_name": "Dot Info",
          "label": "Methanol Sol.",
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

then I am getting error:

```
Variants must have the the same list option display names.
```

And when I am passing parameters like this:

```
{
  "name": "Product name",
  "type": "physical",
  "sku": "CDID-12345",
  "description": "Description",
  "weight": 0,
  "width": 0,
  "depth": 0,
  "height": 0,
  "price": 0,
  "cost_price": 0,
  "retail_price": 0,
  "sale_price": 0,
  "categories": [1],
  "variants": [
    {
      "cost_price": 0,
      "price": 0,
      "weight": 0,
      "sku": "MP091236",
      "option_values": [
        {
          "option_display_name": "Size",
          "label": "1L Glass Amber",
        },
        {
          "option_display_name": "Self Life",
          "label": "",
        },
        {
          "option_display_name": "Dot Info",
          "label": "",
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "cost_price": 0,
      "price": 0,
      "weight": 0,
      "sku": "MP091239",
      "option_values": [
        {
          "option_display_name": "Size",
          "label": "500ml Glass Amber",
        },
        {
          "option_display_name": "Self Life",
          "label": "12",
        },
        {
          "option_display_name": "Dot Info",
          "label": "Methanol Sol.",
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

then I am getting error like this:

```
"variants.0.option_values.1.label": "label must be a string"
```

How can I create two SKUs of this product where one will have options Size                 , Self Life and Dot info and other having Size as only option.

Comment: did you try null? or try giving a space as value

Comment: passing Null is returning error "label must be a string". And giving a space as value is working but that is not correct way as it is creating " " as a product option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case seems like you want `Self Life` and be `Dot Info` as non required modifiers instead rather than as options

Basically you will create 2 variants each having option values as shown below on above endpoint

```
"variants": [
{
   ...
    "option_values": [
    {
      "option_display_name": "Size",
      "label": "1L Glass Amber",
    }
  ]
}
{
    ...
    "option_values": [
    {
      "option_display_name": "Size",
      "label": "500ml Glass Amber",
    }
  ]
}
```

and then create 2 modifiers (one with `display_name`: `Self Life` other with `display_name`:  `Dot Info`) by posting twice on v3/catalog/products//modifiers

Comment: How we will associate pricing with modifiers?

Comment: you can created adjusters on individual modifiers values which can adjust price,weight, image and purchasing disabled